# Mail.app unable to login to 1&1 mail account after upgrading to macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, high-sierra

I upgraded my iMac to macOS High Sierra 10.13.4. Since then my email account with **1&1** (that was previously working fine) - decided to work intermittently, then just failed completely. I contacted 1&1 and they couldn't help, saying I was using the right login credentials. They even screen shared and were still none the wiser and said it must be an internal problem.

I deleted the account from Mail.app and tried to *Add Account* - but it just says *Unable to verify account or password*. If I ignore that and just carry on filling in the appropriate fields, I get another window *Select the Apps you want to use with this account*. I check *Mail* and press next and there's spinning beachball connection icon for a split second and then nothing happens.

How do I get my mail account with 1&1 to work again with Mail.app?

Comment: I have the same situation: 1. Mail working fine on Sierra with an IMAP server, 2. Upgrade on High Sierra, 3. Mail failing with the same account. ⇒ unrelated to 1&1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution was in the Mail app itself to go to Preferences, select Accounts, and to enter the complete email `myname@myisp.de` as user name for my IMAP account.

I also had to change the port for IMAP to 993 and for SMTP to 465 (for secure connections via SSL.)